# MS SQL including 'AND' & 'OR' breaks query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to run a query that selects where db1.specific is equal to either 'OO' or 'AA', but running my query breaks

Here's what I've tried

```
SELECT        *lots*
FROM            db1 INNER JOIN
                         db2 ON db1.id = db2.id
WHERE        (db1.num = 2353) AND (db1.specific = 'OO') OR
                         (db1.specific = 'AA')
```

the query runs fine and returns 12 entries without the `OR
                             (db1.specific = 'AA')`.
But with the OR statement added it seems to run a select * or something (query keeps going, thousands of entries)

I've tried to place the OR differently or re arrange the query but haven't had any luck.

Comment: What kind of boolean logic are you trying to write? A&&B or A&&C? or is it really A&&B OR C? Currently, if only C is true, the row will be returned. AND takes precedences over OR. Add parenthesis around the 'OO' and 'AA' clauses.

Comment: `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, that's why you get the "unexpected" results. Use the answers below with the parenthesis or: `WHERE (db1.num = 2353) AND (db1.specific IN ('OO','AA'))`

Comment: Incidentally, a `SELECT *` would be fetching more *columns*, not more *rows* as is the case with your query. What you are seeing is that the filter in the `WHERE` clause is not filtering as you intended, for the reason others have pointed out. (You did say "or something", but I thought understanding the distinction might help you understand other problems you encounter.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to adjust your parenthesis so that your order of operations is correct....

```
SELECT *lots*
FROM db1 INNER JOIN
db2 ON db1.id = db2.id
WHERE (db1.num = 2353) AND 
(db1.specific = 'OO' OR db1.specific = 'AA')
```

Comment: Or rather, *better* sets of parentheses: the ones included in the question are redundant, the ones added here to group the two side of the `OR` as a single argument to the `AND` are all you need.

Answer (score 1):

A little grouping and you'd have nailed it. Try this.

```
SELECT       *lots*
FROM         db1 INNER JOIN db2 ON db1.id = db2.id
WHERE        (db1.num = 2353) AND ((db1.specific = 'OO') OR (db1.specific = 'AA'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *lots* FROM  db1 INNER JOIN db2 ON db1.id = db2.id WHERE (db1.num = 2353) AND ((db1.specific = 'OO') OR (db1.specific = 'AA'))
```